# Compute distance between source and target tables and find shortest path

Tags: c#, shortest-path

i 've a relation ship table which defines the relation ship between tables.

-------    ---------
source      target  
 
-------    ---------
table1       table2 
--------   ---------
table1       table3 
--------   ---------
table3       table4 
--------   ---------
table2       table4 
--------   ---------
table4       table5 
--------   ---------

and so on

I've a program that gives the tables to query on and let us say it gives three tables to query on -- table1,table3,table5

Now i need to join these tables with the shortest path available -- that is
join table1-->table3 and then I need to add **table4** in the list so that I can join
table5.

So my path should be (table1 - join table3) -- result join (table4) -- result join table5
How to achieve this.
Please give me some suggestions or psuedo code to start with.

Thanks

Comment: Please tell me that your tables are not those of a relational database ?

Comment: yes they're not from relational database but have relations defined.

Comment: You are already using the term "shortest path". So have you researched shortest-path algorithms? Look e.g. into [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm "Wikipedia article"). Assume equal weights (1) for all transitons in your "relationship table". The Wikipedia article includes pseudocode.